# "Welcome to WordPress" Plugin Required Error

Tags: plugins, wp-error

I'm getting this error every time I install or update a plugin on WordPress.

```
defined( 'WTWP__INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH' ) or define( 'WTWP__INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH', 'welcome-to-wordpress/welcome-to-wordpress.php' ); function install_wtwp() { global $pagenow; if ( !( 'install.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_REQUEST['step'] ) && 2 == $_REQUEST['step'] ) ) { return; } $active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() ); // Shouldn't happen, but avoid duplicate entries just in case. if ( !empty( $active_plugins ) && false !== array_search( WTWP__INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH, $active_plugins ) ) { return; } $options = array( 'first_login' => false, 'plid' => 1, 'isc' => 'WPHosting1', 'api_url' => 'https://wpqs.secureserver.net/v1/', 'help_url' => 'https://help.securepaynet.net', 'control_panel_url' => 'https://hostingmanager.secureserver.net/Login.aspx', 'key' => 'VgW+sW0HcrDpo5zAXO26bW0nOsqjYfnHeLjIwaF5yTE2LPm9xjIJ69WvKyAAS9bd' ); $active_plugins[] = WTWP__INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH; update_option( 'active_plugins', $active_plugins ); update_option( 'wtwp_options', $options ); } add_action( 'shutdown', 'install_wtwp' ); defined( 'QUICKSETUP_INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH' ) or define( 'QUICKSETUP_INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH', 'quick-setup/quick-setup.php' ); function install_quicksetup() { global $pagenow; if ( !( 'install.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_REQUEST['step'] ) && 2 == $_REQUEST['step'] ) ) { return; } $active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() ); // Shouldn't happen, but avoid duplicate entries just in case. if ( !empty( $active_plugins ) && false !== array_search( QUICKSETUP_INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH, $active_plugins ) ) { return; } $options = array( 'key' => 'VgW+sW0HcrDpo5zAXO26bW0nOsqjYfnHeLjIwaF5yTE2LPm9xjIJ69WvKyAAS9bd', 'api_url' => 'https://wpqs.secureserver.net/v1/', ); $active_plugins[] = QUICKSETUP_INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH; update_option( 'active_plugins', $active_plugins ); add_option( 'gd_quicksetup_last_post', array(), '', false ); update_option( 'gd_quicksetup_options', $options ); } add_action( 'shutdown', 'install_quicksetup' );
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a file called install.php at /wp-content/ directory which contained the line causing the issue:

```
defined( 'WTWP__INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH' ) or define( 'WTWP__INSTALL_PLUGIN_PATH', 'welcome-to-wordpress/welcome-to-wordpress.php' );
```

Upon deleting the file, I was able to resolve the issue.

This is most probably a file that was placed by a hosting provider by default long with a plugin that has been later deleted, causing the error to popup.